moduli of parabolic bundles of rank two on P^1
Consider the moduli space of semistable rank two bundles with trivial determinant on projective line of weight $\frac{1}{2}$,at $n>5$ points.
The Quot scheme is $(\mathbb{P}^1)^n$. Is the strictly semistable locus of codimension at least three?
